# How can I convert a Timestamp into either Date or DateTime object?

Tags: java, datetime, date, jdbc, timestamp

I'm retrieving a timestamp object from a database using `ResultSet.getTimestamp()`, but I'd like an easy way to get the date in the format of `MM/DD/YYYY` and the time in a format of `HH:MM xx`. I was tinkering around, it it looks as though I can do such by making use of the Date and/or DateTime objects within Java. Is that the best way to go, or do I even need to convert the timestamp to accomplish this? Any recommendations would be helpful.

```
....
while(resultSet.next()) {
    Timestamp dtStart = resultSet.getTimestamp("dtStart");
    Timestamp dtEnd = resultSet.getTimestamp("dtEnd");

    // I would like to then have the date and time
    // converted into the formats mentioned...
    ....
}
....
```

Comment: No `DateTime` class is bundled with Java 1 through Java 9.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[`java.sql.Timestamp`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) is a subclass of [`java.util.Date`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html). So, just upcast it.

```
Date dtStart = resultSet.getTimestamp("dtStart");
Date dtEnd = resultSet.getTimestamp("dtEnd");
```

Using [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and creating Joda [`DateTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#DateTime%28long%29) should be straightforward from this point on.

Comment: if jodatime is going to be used `DateTime dtStartDT = new DateTime(resultSet.getTimestamp("dtStart"));` is all that's needed.

Answer (score 25):

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
        Date date = new Date(timestamp.getTime());

        // S is the millisecond
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy' 'HH:mm:ss:S");

        System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.format(timestamp));
        System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.format(date));
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe "MM/dd/yyyy' 'HH:mm:ss:S" is better?

Comment: Of course, minutes are "mm", I corrected the code example.

Answer (score 2):

### java.time

Modern answer: use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work. Back in 2011 it was right to use the `Timestamp` class, but since JDBC 4.2 it is no longer advised.

For your work we need a time zone and a couple of formatters. We may as well declare them static:

```
static ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("America/Marigot");
static DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/uuuu");
static DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm xx");
```

Now the code could be for example:

```
    while(resultSet.next()) {
        ZonedDateTime dtStart = resultSet.getObject("dtStart", OffsetDateTime.class)
                 .atZoneSameInstant(zone);

        // I would like to then have the date and time
        // converted into the formats mentioned...
        String dateFormatted = dtStart.format(dateFormatter);
        String timeFormatted = dtStart.format(timeFormatter);
        System.out.format("Date: %s; time: %s%n", dateFormatted, timeFormatted);
    }
```

Example output (using the time your question was asked):

> Date: 09/20/2011; time: 18:13 -0400

In your database `timestamp with time zone` is recommended for timestamps. If this is what you’ve got, retrieve an `OffsetDateTime` as I am doing in the code. I am also converting the retrieved value to the user’s time zone before formatting date and time separately. As time zone I supplied America/Marigot as an example, please supply your own. You may also leave out the time zone conversion if you don’t want any, of course.

If the datatype in SQL is a mere `timestamp` without time zone, retrieve a `LocalDateTime` instead. For example:

```
        ZonedDateTime dtStart = resultSet.getObject("dtStart", LocalDateTime.class)
                 .atZone(zone);
```

No matter the details I trust you to do similarly for `dtEnd`.

I wasn’t sure what you meant by the `xx` in `HH:MM xx`. I just left it in the format pattern string, which yields the UTC offset in hours and minutes without colon.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Answer (score 1):

You can also get DateTime object from timestamp, including your current daylight saving time:

```
public DateTime getDateTimeFromTimestamp(Long value) {
    TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
    long offset = timeZone.getOffset(value);
    if (offset < 0) {
        value -= offset;
    } else {
        value += offset;
    }
    return new DateTime(value);
}
```

Comment: What is this `DateTime` class? No such class bundled with Java. Did you add Joda-Time to your project? If so, no need to be mixing the troublesome old legacy date-time classes like `Calendar` with Joda-Time, just stick to Joda-Time. Furthermore, the Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode, and advises migration to the modern java.time classes. The java.time classes supplant both the old legacy date-time classes (`Date`, `Calendar`, etc.) and Joda-Time.

Comment: DateTime is class from Joda-Time. OP asked how to convert timestamp into either Date or DateTime. You are right, there is no need for Calendar class here.

Answer (score 0):

`LocalDateTime dtStart = rs.getTimestamp("dtStart").toLocalDateTime();`

Converts this Timestamp object to a code LocalDateTime.
The conversion creates a code LocalDateTime that represents the
same year, month, day of month, hours, minutes, seconds and nanos
date-time value as this code Timestamp in the local time zone.

since 1.8