# Getting Time and Date separately from timestamp

Tags: java

I have a timestamp which I have retrieved from database.
For ex:

```
Timestamp acceptedDate = 2014-10-27 13:39:50;
```

Now I want to get **time part** of the timestamp in a different variable and **date part** of the timestamp in a different variable and also the time should be a 12 hour clock. How can achieve this?

Comment: try with Simpledatefromat http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-date-and-calendar-examples/  http://java67.blogspot.in/2013/01/how-to-format-date-in-java-simpledateformat-example.html

Comment: check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492423/how-can-i-convert-a-timestamp-into-either-date-or-datetime-object

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java string to date conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)

Comment: Please search StackOverflow before posting.

Answer (score 0):

Split to get date and time...

```
String date = acceptedDate.toString().split(" ")[0];
String time = acceptedDate.toString().split(" ")[1];
```

Convert 24 hr to 12 hr format...

```
DateFormat f1 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
Date d = f1.parse(time);
DateFormat f2 = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mma");
f2.format(d).toLowerCase();
time = f2.toString();
```

I hope this helps... :)