# Retrieving a DateTime Using resultset into a DateTime field

Tags: java, datetime, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to retrieve a `DateTime` field from my Database using `resultset` but I couldn't find a `getDateTime()` method, I even tried using `getTimestamp()` but still couldn't be converted to `DateTime`

here's the code :

```
private static Test map(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
    Test test = new Test();
    test.setTestId(resultSet.getLong("TestID"));
    test.setTeacherId(resultSet.getLong("TeacherID"));
    test.setModuleId(resultSet.getLong("ModuleID"));
    test.setLaunchDate(resultSet.getTimestamp("LaunchDate")); //i need to retrieve a DateTime here
    test.setTestType(resultSet.getString("TestType"));
    return test;
}
```

the test code of date:

```
test.setLaunchDate(DateTime datetime){
   this.LaunchDate = datetime;
}
```

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492423/how-can-i-convert-a-timestamp-into-either-date-or-datetime-object

Comment: thank you so much it is the solution I've been looking for